# View graphml file

Tags: ubuntu, graphml

I recently found a .graphml file but have no idea how to open it from command line. Do I need to install something to view such files in ubuntu from command line? I tried google but could not find any result related to this topic.

Comment: GraphMl viewer for network visualization [example](https://github.com/Abhi5h3k/graphml-viewer)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Graphml is the standard file format for [graph yED editor](http://www.yworks.com/en/products/yfiles/yed/). This editor can be downloaded on any platform (linux, mac ,windows).

The documentation about the graphml format itself, xml-based, can be found [here](http://docs.yworks.com/yfiles/doc/developers-guide/graphml.html).

Answer (score 1):

[grpahviz](https://graphviz.org/) comes with a [tool](https://graphviz.org/docs/cli/graphml2gv/) to translate graphml to [dot language](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html).

For simple visualizations you can do:

```
graphml2gv input.graphml  | dot -Tpdf -o out.pdf
```